# iOS: How to update/reload tableview when swip pages in container view

Tags: xcode

I have a question on my app,

The main view (mainviewcontroller.h)consists of 2 views, 1 container view and 1 tableview, inside the container view it's a pageviewcontroller (pageviewcontroller.h) which controls 5 pages, 5 pages share same viewcontroller(uiviewcontroller.h)

Question is when I swip through the pages, I want the tableview reload data according to the page.

The data in table view is coming from a preloaded database. I can get different table of data by changing predicates keywords in the fetch request, but how can I somehow link the changing of page in the pageviewcontroller to change of predicate in the fetch request.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some code to describe what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Basiclly in the tableview fetch request I can set predicate to filter whatever dataset I want from database. I want this predicate string/keyword to be changed according to the currently shown page in the pageviewcontroller. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone please? I'm stuck. Thanks.